# iOS checking if root certificate is installed *and* trusted

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl

Our app is installing a root CA profile, and I want to verify it is installed and trusted by the user.

Currently this is roughly what we do (trimmed it for the core)

```
SecPolicyRef policyObj = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
SecTrustRef trustObj;
OSStatus error = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates((__bridge CFTypeRef _Nonnull)(fullChain), policyObj, &trustObj);

SecTrustResultType result;
error = SecTrustEvaluate(trustObj, &result);

CFRelease(trustObj);
CFRelease(policyObj);

return (kSecTrustResultUnspecified == result || kSecTrustResultProceed == result);
```

The problem is this, once the profile is installed the result is either kSecTrustResultUnspecified (iOS 10~) or kSecTrustResultProceed (iOS 11~)
But I want to check if user trusted it (under General->About->Trust Settings)

I dug around apple's docs and found nothing, moreover in the [SecTrustEvaluate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1394363-sectrustevaluate) doc it says return value 'proceed' means user trusted the cert.

`proceed— The user explicitly chose to trust a certificate in the chain (usually by clicking a button in a certificate trust panel).`

Anyone has idea how this can be done? what am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after digging around i found out that SecPolicyCreateSSL is working as expect, still not 100% why SecPolicyCreateBasicX509 is not.

So for future ref if someone have this issue, this is what we did instead,

```
SecPolicyRef policy = SecPolicyCreateSSL(true, NULL);
SecTrustRef testTrust;

OSStatus status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates((__bridge CFArrayRef)fullChain, policy, &testTrust);
status = SecTrustEvaluate(testTrust, &trustResult);

CFRelease(testTrust);
CFRelease(policy);

return (status == errSecSuccess) && (kSecTrustResultUnspecified == trustResult || kSecTrustResultProceed == trustResult);;
```

(basically using SecPolicyCreateSSL instead)

Answer (score 2):

Improoved Objective-C code by @Al Ga, it tested and work on iOS 13/14

```
   SecPolicyRef policyObj = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
   SecTrustRef trustObj;
   
   NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"certName" ofType:@"crt"];
   NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
   CFDataRef certCFR = (__bridge CFDataRef)certData;
   SecCertificateRef certSCR = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, certCFR);
   
   NSArray* certArray = @[ (__bridge id)certSCR ];
   
   OSStatus error = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates((__bridge CFTypeRef _Nonnull)certArray, policyObj, &trustObj);

   SecTrustResultType result;
   error = SecTrustEvaluate(trustObj, &result);
```

**SecTrustResultType result** will be contain **uint32_t** :

- kSecTrustResultInvalid  = 0
- kSecTrustResultProceed  = 1 //**root cert Installed**
- kSecTrustResultConfirm  = 2
- kSecTrustResultDeny  =  3
- kSecTrustResultUnspecified  = 4
- kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure = 5 //**root cert Doesn't installed**
- kSecTrustResultFatalTrustFailure  = 6
- kSecTrustResultOtherError = 7